# multithreading in javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Is multithreading possible in javascript?
This is my javascript part of my JSP page. 
I have this 4 if conditions. The copde in 4 if conditions will run 4 diagnostic tests.  But I want to run them simultaneously. is it possible?

```
  if(document.getElementById("VoiceNode").style.display=="block" && document.getElementById("voiceTest-0").style.display=="none"){
                   alert("calling voice test");          
                    document.getElementById("voiceTest-0").style.display="block";
                    kbdOnnetVoiceTestAjaxCall.init('<%=contextPath%>','<%=Service.getServiceID()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getTelephoneNumber()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getPort()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getDslam()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getSlot()%>','${KBDResultsTimeout}','true')
                    document.getElementById("moreVoice").style.display="block";
                    alert("exiting voice test"); 
                }
                if(document.getElementById("sessionTest-0").style.display=="none"){
                                       document.getElementById("sessionTest-0").style.display="block";
                    kbdOnnetSessionTestAjaxCall.init('<%=contextPath%>','<%=Service.getServiceID()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getTelephoneNumber()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getPort()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getDslam()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getSlot()%>','${KBDResultsTimeout}','true')
                    document.getElementById("moreSession").style.display="block";  
                                    }
                if(document.getElementById("lineTest-0").style.display=="none"){

                    document.getElementById("lineTest-0").style.display="block";
                    kbdOnnetLineTestAjaxCall.init('<%=contextPath%>','<%=Service.getServiceID()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getTelephoneNumber()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getPort()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getDslam()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getSlot()%>','${KBDResultsTimeout}','true')
                    document.getElementById("moreLine").style.display="block";
                                     }
                if (document.getElementById("syncTest-0").style.display=="none"){

                    document.getElementById("syncTest-0").style.display="block";
                    kbdOnnetSyncTestAjaxCall.init('<%=contextPath%>','<%=Service.getServiceID()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getTelephoneNumber()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getPort()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getDslam()%>','<%=Service.getInventory().getSlot()%>','${KBDResultsTimeout}','true')
                    document.getElementById("moreSync").style.display="block";
                                        }
```

Comment: Two words. Web workers. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs, those are two words

Answer (score 1):

No

You can rearrange the execution order in the event loop. But they can never happen at the same time.

Comment: Web workers is browser feature and not javascript related. When you create a new Web worker the _browser_ (not javascript it self) run it in a separated thread from your "window" thread.

Comment: I always thought that you could use web worker to multithread your javascript.

Comment: If we cannot perform multi-threading in javascript then how does the JS Game Engines work?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a single-threaded. But

- you can emulate "threading" by [setting tasks aside](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2009/07/03/not-blocking-the-ui-in-tight-javascript-loops) using `setTimeout`. This is commonly used to prevent "UI blocking" during intensive operations.
- or use the recent [WebWorkers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)